# java.sql.SQLException while pass variable into oracle procedure from java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, ebean

When I'm trying to pass variable into this procedure:

```
PROCEDURE REMOVAL_ATR_PR340_FR73_S1_T1(
  p_POE_STEAM_TURBINES_VID NUMBER,
  p_PERIOD_ID              NUMBER,
  p_STOP_ID                in out number,
  p_REMOVAL_LAST_YEAR      in out NUMBER
)
IS
BEGIN       
    SELECT pr.STOP_ID,
           pr.REMOVAL_LAST_YEAR
    INTO   p_STOP_ID,
           p_REMOVAL_LAST_YEAR
    FROM   FORMS fr
           LEFT JOIN PR340_FR73_S1_T1 pr
           ON pr.FORMS_ID = fr.ID
    WHERE  PERIOD_ID = p_PERIOD_ID - 1
    AND    pr.POE_STEAM_TURBINES_VID = p_POE_STEAM_TURBINES_VID;
END REMOVAL_ATR_PR340_FR73_S1_T1;
```

This error arrise:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

This code call the procedure:

```
String sql = "{call REA.FILL_EVENT.REMOVAL_ATR_PR340_FR73_S1_T1("  + doc.poeSteamTurbine.vid + "," + doc.form.periodId +"," + 0 +  "," + 0 +") } ";
    CallableSql cs = Ebean.createCallableSql(sql);
    cs.registerOut(3, Types.INTEGER);
    cs.registerOut(4, Types.INTEGER);
    Ebean.execute(cs);
    Integer retValue = (Integer) cs.getObject(3);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're selecting the value of the third column in a query that only returns two columns of data per row

Comment: You don't have any parameter placeholders in your query, so using `registerOut` won't work.

Comment: how to add  parameter placeholders?

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to put the values into the statement but use `?` characters instead to add parameter placeholders (see the first line of my answer). Then you can use the `setParameter` method to specify input values and `registerOut` for out parameters. See the [documentation](https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/CallableSql.html).

Comment: that's what I did, but errors occur

Answer (score 0):

Use bind variables:

```
String sql = "{call REA.FILL_EVENT.REMOVAL_ATR_PR340_FR73_S1_T1(?,?,?,?) } ";
CallableSql cs = Ebean.createCallableSql(sql);
cs.setParameter(1,doc.poeSteamTurbine.vid);
cs.setParameter(2,doc.form.periodId);
cs.setParameter(3,0);
cs.registerOut(3, Types.INTEGER);
cs.setParameter(4,0);
cs.registerOut(4, Types.INTEGER);
Ebean.execute(cs);
Integer retValue = (Integer) cs.getObject(3);
```

Comment: Your code does not change anything, but added error
 Error with property [5] dt [4] data [0] [java.lang.Integer]

Answer (score 0):

It work :

```
String sql = "{call REA.FILL_EVENT.REMOVAL_ATR_PR340_FR73_S1_T1(?,?,?,?) } ";
        CallableSql cs = Ebean.createCallableSql(sql);
        cs.setParameter(1,doc.poeSteamTurbine.vid);
        cs.setParameter(2,doc.form.periodId);
        cs.registerOut(3, Types.INTEGER);
        cs.registerOut(4, Types.INTEGER);
        Ebean.execute(cs);
        doc.prevStopId = (Integer) cs.getObject(3);
        doc.prevRemovalLastYear = (Integer) cs.getObject(4);
        return doc;
```

Comment: This isn't that different from the [answer by MT0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41588939/466862), except for the absence of those `setParameter` calls for index 3 and 4.